# SQL Server Stored Procedure - Does Raiserror affect performance

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Does `RAISERROR` in a SQL Server stored procedure affect performance?

Would I be better off just having a try-catch wrapper around the whole procedure and just catch the errors in the database access layer?

Right now for logging in a user, I check if the user exists and `RAISERROR` if the user does not exist. Would I better just let the procedure return null and interpret that in the database access layer?

Comment: It's better to use THROW according to the documentation but RAISEERROR is very common.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: That's your architectural decision. With these trivial (performance-wise) tasks, you should lean on the side of maintainability and readability of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry about performance in this situation.
I would go with raising an error for 2 reasons:

1. You quit earlier (when you find out user does not exist), and make a clear message.
2. IMHO raising an error is more readable and makes your code clearer.